# Relationship between tables but different server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is this possible to create any relationship between two tables but different server? I know we can’t do primary key/foreign key relationship but is there any other way to do it in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have have a physical relationship between two different servers but you can create a Linked Server and then use a four part name in your query.

INNER JOIN [server].[schema].[Table] ON [server].[schema].[Table].[ColumnName] = LocalDBTable.ColumnName

That allows you to related data across servers. Hope that helps.